# What do I need to get the contents of li items

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to get the text in a within the span inside the li items.
I'm trying to do this with jquery.

```
  <ul class="category-path breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="/" title="/">Home</a></li>
        <li ><a href="/saat" itemprop="url" title="Saat"><span itemprop="title">Watches</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/erkek-saatleri" itemprop="url" title="Erkek Saat"><span itemprop="title">man watches</span></a></li>
        <li ><a href="" itemprop="url" title="NACAR"><span itemprop="title">NACAR</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

the code I tried

```
  $(".breadcrumb li").each(function (index) {
            var bread = $(this + "a span").text();
            window.alert(bread + index);
        });
```

Comment: Try `var bread = $(this).find("span").text();`

Comment: Or you can do `$('a span', this).text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments you can use either `$(this).find("a span").text()` or `$("a span", this).text()`. Further, you can use `:has(span)` in order to target just the `li` elements that have a `span` element:

```
$(".breadcrumb li:has(span)").each(function(index) {
  var bread = $("a span", this).text();
  console.log(bread + index);
  var brd = $(this).find("a span").text();
  console.log( brd );
});
```

Also, you can get all the text in an array as follows:

```
var loaves = $(".breadcrumb span").map((index, span) => `${span.textContent}${index}`).get();
console.log( loaves );
```

**DEMO**

```js
//One by one ... Use :has(span) to target only li elements with a span
$(".breadcrumb li:has(span)").each(function(index) {
  var bread = $("a span", this).text();
  console.log(bread + index);
  var brd = $(this).find("a span").text();
  console.log( brd );
});

//All together in an array
var loaves = $(".breadcrumb span").map((index, span) => `${span.textContent}${index}`).get();
console.log( loaves );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="category-path breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="/" title="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/saat" itemprop="url" title="Saat"><span itemprop="title">Watches</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="/erkek-saatleri" itemprop="url" title="Erkek Saat"><span itemprop="title">man watches</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="" itemprop="url" title="NACAR"><span itemprop="title">NACAR</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try the below code. It will work for you to get span content in every list items.**

```
$(".breadcrumb li span").each(function () {
        window.alert($(this).text());
});
```